# Difference between uint can be negative

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I have a question about unsigned integer in C/C++. They and the results of operations on them should always be positive or equal to zero but it does not look the case with uint16_t difference. uint are defined in the C++ header cstdint.

The next program takes the "wrong" branch:

```
uint16_t beg = 7;
uint16_t end = 6;
uint16_t zero = 0;

if (end - beg >= zero) cout << "This branch is always taken.\n";
else cout << "This branch will never be taken.\n";
```

I tested in my computer (gcc 9.3.0) and on Compiler Explorer with same result.

To fix that, I have to cast the difference to uint16_t:

```
if (uint16_t(end - beg) >= zero) cout << "This branch is always taken.\n";
else cout << "This branch will never be taken.\n";
```

Comment: Arithmetic operators automatically convert types smaller than `int` to `int` before doing anything with them, see [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Comment: Look up "integer promotions", e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion.  Since every `uint16_t` can be represented by `int`, the operands of `-` are promoted to `int`, the subtraction is done as `int` (signed!) and the result has type `int`.

Comment: The result changes with uint32_t

Comment: It's one of those "Gotcha's" that leads to sad bugs... all works with legitimate inputs until at some inconvenient time when it fails (I see this as a flaw in C++ design)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the C++ standard requires to promote the operands and the result to signed int. In my opinion, it makes more sense to get uint16_t as result of operations on uint16_t. By the way, I compiled with all the flags on (-Wextra -Wpedantic -Wall -Wconversion) and I did not received any waring. Since my code has to run on Arduino and Raspberry, I need to specify the length of uint. It took one hour to debug that piece of code to me. In my opinion, if C++ committee wants more people to use C++, they should fix those things. Sorry for the rant.

Answer (score 9):

Because of integer promotion.

In [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion):

> 4. Otherwise, both operands are integers. Both operands undergo
>    integer promotions (see below); then, after integer promotion, one of
>    the following cases applies:
>
> > The unsigned type has conversion rank less than the signed type:
> > If the signed type can represent all values of the unsigned type, then
> > the operand with the unsigned type is implicitly converted to the
> > signed type.

Because all `uint16_t` values can be represented as an `int` (32 bits), it gets promoted to an `int`. Because `6 - 7 = -1`, the condition is `false`

---

Worth noting that if C++ compilers decide to use 16 bits for an `int`, this doesn't hold anymore. Because not all `uint16_t` values can be held in a 16 bits `int`, it doesn't get promoted anymore. `6 - 7` now cause an wrap-around, and become `true`

Comment: Correct for compilers that use 32-bit `int`, i.e., all the ones that you're likely to encounter as a beginner. However, C++ compilers can use just 16 bits for an `int`, and if that's the case, the type of `uint16_t` values will be `unsigned int`, and the result goes the other way. +1.

Comment: "decide to use 16 bits for an int" sounds a bit strange. Some C++ compilers do for some architectures.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the C++ standard requires to promote the operands and the result to signed int. In my opinion, it makes more sense to get uint16_t as result of operations on uint16_t. By the way, I compiled with all the flags on (-Wextra -Wpedantic -Wall -Wconversion) and I did not received any waring. Since my code has to run on Arduino and Raspberry, I need to specify the length of uint. It took one hour to debug that piece of code to me. In my opinion, if C++ committee wants more people to use C++, they should fix those things. Sorry for the rant.

Answer (score 1):

When the bit-width of `int` (commonly 32) is wider than `end, beg` (16), `end - beg` is like `(int)end - (int)beg` with an `int` result - potentially negative.

> To fix that, I have to cast the difference to `uint16_t`:

```
// OP's approach
if (uint16_t(end - beg) >= zero) cout << "This branch is always taken.\n";
else cout << "This branch will never be taken.\n";
```

That is one way.

Another way to drive code to use `unsigned` math:

```
// Suggested alternative
// if (uint16_t(end - beg) >= zero) ...
if (0u + end - beg >= zero) ...
```

This will cause *unsigned* math throughout `0u + end - beg >= zero`<sup>*1</sup>.

The trouble with *casts* is one of code maintenance.  Should code later use `uint32_t beg, end`, consider the now bug `uint16_t(end - beg)`.

True that any local code change warrants a larger review, it is simply that gentle nudges to use `unsigned` math typically cause less issues and less maintenance than casts.  The nudge never *narrows*.  A cast may widened or narrow.

---

**Deeper**

The core issues lies with using *unsigned* types narrower than `int/unsigned`.  When able, avoid this for non-array objects like `beg, end, ...`.  When obliged to use small *unsigned* types that may be narrower than `unsigned`, take care to insure the desired *unsigned/signed* math is used on these objects.

From time-to-time, I wanted a `uint_N_and_at_least_unsigned_width_t` type to avoid this very problem.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Unless `beg, end` later become a *signed* integer type wider than `unsigned`.  In which case, usually the wider *signed* math **is** preferred.